# Exception at the BufferedReader.reset() method

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, ioexception

I have a hasNext() method for reading a file. It returns true if it's not the end of the file.
In this method it has an Exception.

Exception Information:

- Exception at:  java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:497)
- Typ: java.io.IOException
- Message: Mark invalid

My hasNext() method:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    try {
        super.getSourceRead().mark(1);
        if (super.getSourceRead().read() < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        getSourceRead().reset();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.exceptionOccurred(e);
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Logger.exceptionOccurred(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Scis I'm working with jdk 1.5

Comment: Could you try using `.mark(2)` ?

Comment: @Scis Now it works!! But why that? Thanks :)

Comment: you're very welcome ^^ , the explanation is in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as it's written in the [doc for 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29):

> After reading **this many** characters, attempting to reset the stream may
>   fail.

So in your case it says it *may* fail after reading 1 character.

Setting the limit to 2 puts us in the safe zone.

And just to make a nagging style remark: I hope you have a constant or a member for that limit somewhere in your class (sorry I had to  :) )